# How can I use decodeSampledBitmapFromResource With a downloaded pic?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

Im downloading a photo from the internet, and then saving it in a Bitmap variable.

Im trying to fix the crash it causes (its a memory issue).

Thats the code they suggest here: [Loading Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap)

But they only talk about images that come from resources, so im stuck..

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Can I convert this somehow to make it work with a downloaded bitmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);` you can use it to decode from inputStream. However, it can only run once because the `inputStream` can only be used once. Therefore, you can't really calculate the `inSampleSize` by calling `decodeStream` twice. If you know the size of the image you are downloading, try to hard code the `inSampleSize`.

```
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2; \\ hard code it to whatever is reasonable
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```

Comment: Well, if the decode stream is proper, you should be able to get the image dimensions from the headers/meta without downloading the entire image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can decode Bitmap. And I advise you to calculate dynamically the inSampleSize.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Context context, Uri uri,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
                                                   throws FileNotFoundException {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to calculate inSampleSize from a InputStream :
The key is that we should cache the data read from inputStream

```
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
byte[] data = Utils.streamToBytes(in);
BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
option.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, option);
option.inSampleSize = Utils.getBitmapSampleSize(option.outWidth, reqWidth);
option.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, option);
```

Utils.streamToBytes:

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 int len = 0;
 while((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, len);
 }
 output.close();
 in.close();
 return output.toByteArray();
```